# How can you find a user in a set of users in a Meteor collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

Using MeteorJS, I have a collection of Arrests with a set of userIds that have saved specific Arrests. Those userIds are added using this method:

```
saveArrest: function(arrestId) {
    check(this.userId, String);
    check(arrestId, String);
    var affected = Arrests.update({
        _id: arrestId,
        savers: {$ne: this.userId}
    }, {
        $addToSet: {savers: this.userId},
        $inc: {saves: 1}
    });
    if(! affected)
        throw new Meteor.Error('invalid', "You weren't able to save that arrest");
},
```

I am attempting to find Arrests that the logged in User has saved using the data feature in a route controller with Iron Router.

Here are the two involved controllers:

```
ArrestsNewController = RouteController.extend({
template: 'arrestsNew',
increment: 16, 
arrestsLimit: function() { 
    return parseInt(this.params.arrestsLimit) || this.increment; 
},
findOptions: function() {
    return {sort: this.sort, limit: this.arrestsLimit()};
},
searchOptions: function() {
    return this.search;
},
subscriptions: function() {
    this.postsSub = Meteor.subscribe('arrestsNew', this.findOptions());
},
arrests: function() {
    return Arrests.find(this.searchOptions(), this.findOptions());
},
data: function() {
    var hasMore = this.arrests().count() === this.arrestsLimit();
    var nextPath = this.route.path({arrestsLimit: this.arrestsLimit() + this.increment});
    return {
        arrests: this.arrests(),
        ready: this.postsSub.ready,
        nextPath: hasMore ? this.nextPath() : null
    };
}
});

MyArrestsController = ArrestsNewController.extend({
    sort: {saves: -1, system_id: -1},
    search: {savers : {$in : [this.userId]}},
    nextPath: function() {
        return Router.routes.myArrests.path({arrestsLimit: this.arrestsLimit() + this.increment})
    }
});
```

I think the issue is with **search**: in MyArrestController. That returns no Arrests even though there arrests with the logged in user. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So on save you have `savers: {$ne: this.userId}` - means "Update if the field is not equal to the user Id" and on query you have `search: {savers : {$in : [this.userId]}}` - Means "get data if the userId is inside the array savers".

What's savers? a field or an array? I'm assuming that you want the array, so you should use `$nin`. Documentation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/

You have a bug on `if(! affected)`, you need to pass a callback that checks the result async, not sync. Documentation: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Mongo-Collection-update

Also check wrapAsync: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_wrapasync

I'm naturally open to new ways of writing code but I never place logic code in a RouteController. The type of operation that I used the most is waitOn (to subscribe to data), data, onBeforeAction, onAfterAction and onStop. I used this only for the Route, not logic but of course, it's just a matter of taste.

I find it cleaner and easier to place the "controller" near the Template helpers.

Did you declare `MyArrestsController` as your route controller in the route definition?

```
this.route('arrest', {
    path: '/arrests',
    controller: 'MyArrestsController'
});
```

On `this.postsSub = Meteor.subscribe('arrestsNew', this.findOptions());`, you're not waiting for the data to be available.

Comment: I was showing the way savers are added for reference. You are correct, savers is an array. I am trying to display all Arrest records that have the currently logged in user as a saver. So I need to find all arrests where savers includes this.userId. It's not returning anything though.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you share the GitHub repo.